# Error "Object was not found" on bind Kestrel to https 443 port running inside docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, https, kestrel-http-server

I have a dotnet core app that that needs to run inside a windows core container and expose 443 port (https)

I passed the certificate to the container, set up the environment variables for user path and password.
The application is able to find de certificate but fails with the following error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Object was not found.
```

The certificate is a seft-signed certificate for localhost domain.

I try to add the server localhost to the docker container but also didn't work.

It is not a problem with the certificate password or the certificate location because those problems give explicit errors.

Here docker relevant configuration files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
VOLUME c:/certificates 
COPY . .

#place to put the https certificate
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443"
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8243  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webApp.dll"]
```

The docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.4' 
services:  
  webApp:
    container_name:  webApp    
    build:
      context: ..\webApp\
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: d:/certificates
       target: c:/certificates        
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=somepass
     - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=c:\certificates\servercert.pfx     
    ports:
      - "8243:443"
    extra_hosts:
     - "localhost:127.0.0.1"      
    networks:
       - net
 
networks: 
  net:
```

How to run:

```
docker-compose run wepApp
```

The full error stack:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Object was not found.
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Object was not found.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Backoffice.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\BackOffice\Program.cs:line 12
```

I should be missing something basic once the problem is running DotNet Core on a windows container using https. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by running the container with user `ContainerAdministrator`

The problem many not surface always, it looks related with the image used.
For more information about this issue check [github](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/915)

To set the user on docker-compose.yaml file add:

```
services:  
   wepApp:
      user:  "ContainerAdministrator"
```

To set from the command line:

```
> docker-compose run --user ContainerAdministrator wepApp
```

Comment: After days of pulling my hair out and Googling and using ChatGPT4, I was at the point of giving up learning Docker! Found this at the 11th hour. Life saver. Thank you!