# How to use development certificate from windows host machine on windows docker container running .net core

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

it's a dotnet core app and running it inside a windows container. port 80 and 443 (https) are exposed.

I'm using the default Dockerfile generated by VS

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj", "IdentityServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IdentityServer"
RUN dotnet build "IdentityServer.csproj" -c Development -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IdentityServer.csproj" -c Development -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer.dll","--environment=Development"]
```

I'm following this [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0) & [Developing ASP.NET Core Applications with Docker over HTTPS](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md) to build docker images using host windows system development certificate.

Ran these 2 commands as per the articles above. I made sure the certificate name, in this case (IdentityServer.pfx) match the project assembly name.

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx -p crypticpassword
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

than using the following command to create an image

```
docker build -t identity -f IdentityServer/Dockerfile .
```

after the image is build successfully which I can confirm image is successfully created by running the command

```
docker images ls
```

After all this I'm running the command as per the articles

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 -p 8081:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8081 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="crypticpassword" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=$env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ --user ContainerAdministrator identity
```

The above command fails with the following error

*Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx'.*

> info: Duende.IdentityServer.Startup[0]
> Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer Unhandled exception.
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path 'C:\Users\Administrator.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx'.    at
> Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions
> options)    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String
> fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share,
> FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)    at
> System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions
> options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)    at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)    at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.ImportFromPemFile(String certPemFilePath)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
> host)    at Program.$(String[] args) in
> C:\src\IdentityServer\Program.cs:line 14

[image]

I'm not using User secrets to save the password which is different to the articles.

Any idea What I'm doing wrong here :(

I also referred to this [stack overflow existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195353/error-object-was-not-found-on-bind-kestrel-to-https-443-port-running-inside-do) but it doesn't help

**UPDATE:**

Now I've also added the user secrets as below

```
{
    "Kestrel":{
        "Certificates":{
            "Default":{
                "Path":     "/root/.aspnet/https/<AppName>>.pfx",
                "Password": "<<Your-Password>>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to make it work with following steps. I don't think all of these steps required other than the change in the **docker run command**.

**1. Remove existing dev certificates**

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

**2. Create, trust and export your new development certificate**

Generate a new self-signed certificate, trust it and also export it to a password-protected .pfx file, all in a single step, otherwise it won't work properly.

In the same PowerShell prompt, run the following command, replacing SECRETPASSWORD with a secret password of your own choosing:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust -ep
$env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p SECRETPASSWORD
```

3. Change in the docker run command

for environment variable **ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path**. I changed the value form pointing to host system drive to the drive on docker i.e. change value ***$env:USERPROFILE.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx*** to ***c:\https\IdentityServer.pfx*** . updated command will be

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 -p 8081:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8081 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="crypticpassword" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=c:\https\IdentityServer.pfx -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ --user ContainerAdministrator identity
```